# VBScript is not executing file in AppData folder

Tags: windows, vbscript

I have a VBScript where I downloaded a file into a folder in AppData\Roaming, but when I tried to execute it I get a CMD window that briefly opens for a second and then disappears but the program does not actually run.

Is there something missing with permissions? I have even tried running the VBScript as administrator but I got the same results.

The commands I use are:

```
exeStart = "C:\users\user\AppData\Roaming\exe_folder\exe.exe"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute exeStart, "", "", "", 0
```

This doesn't seem to work either:

```
exeStart = "C:\users\user\AppData\Roaming\exe_folder\exe.exe"    
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
objShell.Run exeStart, 1, True
```

Comment: I want to add that I can run this file like normal from the command line.

Comment: For debugging run `objShell.Run "cmd /k %APPDATA%\exe_folder\exe.exe", 1, True` so you can see what's going on.